# Get element with xml dom parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

How to get restaurant name in jbeil only using xml DOM parser , please help :
And this is my XML file

```
 <city>

 <beirut>
     <restaurant>
       <name>sada</name>
     </restaurant>
</beirut>

<jbeil>
     <restaurant>
       <name>sada</name>
     </restaurant>
</jbeil>

 <sour>     
     <restaurant>
       <name>sada</name>
     </restaurant>
 </sour>

 </city>
```

I want to get the name of restaurant in Jbeil using dom parser and this code give me restaurants name in all city's:

```
 try {  
     File inputFile = new File("src/josephXml.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 
        = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();


     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Restaurant");

     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);


       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 


            jTextArea1.append( "\n"+"Name      :   "+ eElement
              .getElementsByTagName("name")
              .item(0)
              .getTextContent()+"\n "
```

Comment: NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Restaurant");

Comment: What would you think about NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("restaurant");.... there is a small but significant difference R --> r, the rest seems fine so this is only a typo

Comment: no i tried restaurant , it works but give me all restaurant in all city's , i want only restaurant in jbeil , using dom

Comment: Why dont you first get that tag and then from that get restaurant tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use XPath

many resources: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

something like that (not tested)

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;

XPath xPath =  XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
String expression = "/city/jbeil/restaurant/name";
//read a string value
String thename= xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(xmlDocument);
```

Comment: XPath is not so far from DOM. With the direct path to the data, why not use the library made exactly for that ? with the original code, you get all restaurants, and have to loop/for, test ...

Comment: +1 Yeah I agree XPath is better (first I believed he only had a typo on restaurant)  then I saw he did need to skip nodes...

Answer (score 0):

Using the same code style as you and "only using xml DOM parser" get the `jbeil` and then the `restaurant`...

```
    NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("jbeil");
    for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(i);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
            NodeList nList2 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("restaurant");
            for (int n = 0; n < nList.getLength(); n++) {
                Node nNode2 = nList2.item(n);
                if (nNode2.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode;
                    System.out.println(eElement2.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But I would go for the XPath answer...